# Missing JSON data in External Api passed from Express JS

Tags: node.js, express

I have User Register page which is built with ExpressJS. The data entered here by the user should be passed over to an external Api (Java Rest Api). But I am not getting the JSON data at the receiving end. Also I have to send the response only after creating the User. Below are the code snippets:

Here is my ExpressJS code: (I am using Postman app to post the JSON data here)

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);  // JSON sent from Postman is showing correctly

  var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'http://localhost:3000/userCreation',
      body: req.body,
      json: true,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }
  // Here rp is require('request-promise');
  rp(options).then(function (res){
      console.log("Response from external Api: "+res);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
  })
  // The response below should be ideally sent after the User Registration is done. 
  // So it should go into the "then" block. But I am an unable to put it there.
  // It says "cannot send header twice"
  res.send('Json Data sent to Java/MongoDB & User Created successfully.');

});
```

This is the code at the receiving end (Java API - but for now, I have another ExpressJS app to test the flow):

```
router.post('/userCreation', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("User registration in MongoDB");
  console.log(req.hostname);  // O/p : localhost
  console.log(req.body);      // O/p : undefined
  res.send("User successfully created in MongoDB");
});
```

Any help/suggestion on this would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you are using `json`, but send back `text`. Use `res.json` I guess.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I need to change that. But the actual problem lies before that in "rp(options)" statement. Here the options include a body with JSON data, which is not received at the other end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer..... "app.use(bodyParser.json())" was required at both the instances of the ExpressJS server. Now it is working fine.